# making mean points in boxplot bigger and connecting them to each other

Tags: matplotlib, plot, mean, boxplot, marker

is there any way to increase and change the color of the mean points in boxplot matplotlib? I am showing the mean points by setting showmeans=True in box plot, but I can not find how to change the color of the points or increase their sizes. The green points are my mean points. In addition, is it possible to connect them and have a line between them?[image]

Comment: Besides the fact if it's possible - what to argue against a simple additional plot command for the mean values, where you have all opportunities?

Comment: hey SpghttCd, it worked, I add another plot command for the mean values! tnx.

Comment: Always check the documentation first. [Here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/statistics/boxplot.html) is the example that shows how to customize any of the boxplot parameters.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest _Always check the documentation first_ - that's true. but afaics, the "xprops"-parameters of a boxplot do not provide connecting the mean values by a line as requested above, do they? And this would be easily creatable by a simple `plot()` command.

Comment: @SpghttCd Correct, if after customizing the markers as shown in the example you want to connect them, you need to call `plot`, `bxp = ax.boxplot(....)` `ax.plot(*np.squeeze(np.array([l.get_data() for l  in bxp["means"]])).T)`